# Is there an equivalent of MySQL's SHOW CREATE TABLE in Postgres?

Tags: mysql, postgresql, sql

Is there an equivalent of MySQL's `SHOW CREATE TABLE` in Postgres? Is this possible? If not what is the next best solution?

I need the statement because I use it to create the table on an remote server (over WCF).

Comment: Are you looking for a single SQL query statement that would generate a  **CREATE statement**? It **can not** be done in PostgreSQL. In MySQL, that would work because everything can be defined in a single CREATE statement. In PostgreSQL, that would not work because parts are managed as different things. For example, the `AUTO_INCREMENT` of MySQL is managed within its table while the counterpart `SEQUENCE` of PostgreSQL is managed independently. Thus, it would require multiple query statements to fully mimic a single PostgreSQL table. Unlike in MySQL, a single `CREATE` query can work by itself.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

You can try to trace in the PostgreSQL log file what `pg_dump --table table --schema-only` really does. Then you can use the same method to write  your own sql function.

Comment: ok, i traced the pg_dump. But it wasn't as easy, becouse i had to write my own function in C# to write the create table statement. But it was a big help, so thank you veeeeerrrryyyy much. :D

Comment: No need to go to all that trouble - according to [here](https://gist.github.com/Kartones/dd3ff5ec5ea238d4c546) you can use the `-E` option to trace what's going on in the background when you run a `psql` command - `-E: will describe the underlaying queries of the \ commands (cool for learning!)` - HTH!

Answer (score 76):

pg_dump:

```
pg_dump -st tablename dbname
```

or use PostgreSQL GUI Tools(pgAdmin,phpPgAdmin,etc.)

Comment: i'll try to explain the problem in more detail. I need the sql statement (select or stored procedure) becouse I execute the sql command in C# (NpgsqlCommand). So I think the pg_dump is not the solution in this case. :(

Comment: Why not? `--schema-only` has this exact purpose: Show the SQL statements to create the schema/table. You can  than feed this output into your C# program somehow.

Comment: look at the information_schema views: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/interactive/information-schema.html

Comment: @SvenW: I would do that if i'd have a known set of tables. The problem is that the user can, if he chooses to, sync any table in selected database and then create the selected table on a remote server behind a wcf service. I can do that with mssql and now i want to expand the client program to other sql servers (mysql, oracle, postgresql, ...) OK, I can do pg_dump for a table that the user wants to sync, but if it is at all possible to do that just in plsql, i want to do it in plsql

Comment: If dumping to `.tar`, grab the `restore.sql` file from the archive. It has all the create statements.

Answer (score 42):

In command line (`psql`) you can run: `\d <table name>` to list all columns, their types and indexes.

Comment: This is helpful, but doesn't answer the question.

Comment: The question is different.

Comment: Does not answer the question, and can't understand why so many people upvoted this

Comment: Because it's helpful. :) +1

Comment: Answers only have to be **useful**, they don't have to answer the exact question. This is exactly what I was after - I don't need the exact create table statement, just a simple check within the CLI that will show me if the expected change I just applied to the table worked. I don't want the overhead of `pg_dump`.

Answer (score 18):

Building on the first part of @CubicalSoft's answer you can drop in the following function which should work for simple tables (assumes the default 'public' schema' and omits constraints, indexes and user defined data types etc. etc.). @RJS answer is the only way to do it properly at the moment; this is something that should be built into psql!

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION show_create_table(table_name text, join_char text = E'\n' ) 
  RETURNS text AS 
$BODY$
SELECT 'CREATE TABLE ' || $1 || ' (' || $2 || '' || 
    string_agg(column_list.column_expr, ', ' || $2 || '') || 
    '' || $2 || ');'
FROM (
  SELECT '    ' || column_name || ' ' || data_type || 
       coalesce('(' || character_maximum_length || ')', '') || 
       case when is_nullable = 'YES' then '' else ' NOT NULL' end as column_expr
  FROM information_schema.columns
  WHERE table_schema = 'public' AND table_name = $1
  ORDER BY ordinal_position) column_list;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE SQL STABLE;
```

Comment: You might be interested in [this](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=c77a8c3b967dda32db6e25b133d91b46) - only a slight mod to your code means that the DDL can be copied and pasted from `psql` **without** worrying about those pesky `+` signs at the end? HTH...

Answer (score 12):

I realize I'm a bit late to this party, but this was the first result to my Google Search so I figured I'd answer with what I came up with.

You can get pretty far toward a solution with this query to get the columns:

```
SELECT *
FROM information_schema.columns
WHERE table_schema = 'YOURSCHEMA' AND table_name = 'YOURTABLE'
ORDER BY ordinal_position;
```

And then this query for most common indexes:

```
SELECT c.oid, c.relname, a.attname, a.attnum, i.indisprimary, i.indisunique
FROM pg_index AS i, pg_class AS c, pg_attribute AS a
WHERE i.indexrelid = c.oid AND i.indexrelid = a.attrelid AND i.indrelid = 'YOURSCHEMA.YOURTABLE'::regclass
ORDER BY" => "c.oid, a.attnum
```

Then it is a matter of building out the query string(s) in the right format.

Answer (score 3):

Postgres extension ddlx (https://github.com/lacanoid/pgddl) does exactly this and more.

Answer (score 3):

DBeaver is one of the best tools for SQL database management. You can get the table query like `create table table_name` in a very simple way in the DBeaver tool.

- Right-click on the table name.
- Then, Click on Generate SQL and then DDL
  [DDLimage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hozmi.jpg)

Comment: Interestingly, going to the Properties > DDL sub-tab for the table is giving me SQL that is a bit more compact (e.g. it has a single CREATE TABLE containing all constraints whereas Generate SQL > DDL is giving me CREATE TABLE containing all but one of them plus an additional ALTER TABLE to add the last one.

Answer (score 2):

Better

```
pg_dump -U <user> -h <host> -st <tablename> <db name>
```

Comment: Variation that will also leave out SQL COMMENT statements for brevity, and filter out `--` comment lines and duplicate empty lines: `pg_dump -h <host> -p <port> -d <db name> -U <user> -t <tablename> --schema-only --no-comments | sed -e '/^--/d' | sed -e '/^$/N;/^\n$/D'`

Answer (score 1):

In [pgAdmin 4](https://www.pgadmin.org/), just find the table in the tree on the left, e.g.:

```
Servers
+ PostgreSQL 11
  + Databases
    + MYDATABASENAME
      + Schemas
        + public
          + Tables
            + MYTABLENAME  <-- click this tree element
```

When the table is selected, open the **SQL tab** on the right. It displays the `CREATE TABLE` for the selected table.

Answer (score 0):

As answered in https://serverfault.com/a/875414/333439, with the `\d <table>` meta-command in `psql` is possible to show the table structure in database. If you want to view the query used in meta-command, you can use the command `psql -E`. As described in the manpage, the `-E` switch echoes the `\d` meta-commands queries. So, you can launch `psql -E`, you can view the table structure with `\d <table>` meta-command, and, according to `-E` switch, you can view the query generated for describe the table structure

Comment: I can see the SQL commands used to display the output of the "\d table", but I can't see the SQL statement used to create the table.